# Calculate the limit of $(3^n-2^n)^{1/n}$

Tags: limits, analysis

How can I calculate this?

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt[n] {3^n-2^n} $$
I calculated the answer with Matlab and i know that it is 3 and thought that it has to be solved with Sandwich rule. I found an upper limit (3), but I haven't been able to find a sequence, which limit is 3, but it is smaller than the given sequence;

Comment: HINT: This is simply $$3 \cdot \sqrt[n]{1-\left( \frac{2}{3}\right)^n}$$